# PL/SQL - cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, casting

I am trying to get all the column names of **my_table**, and would like to make it as string using **my_fn**. For example, let say **my_table** has columns named **"year"**, **"month"**, **"day"**. Get this column names using **all_tab_cols** table, and store it into **tmp** collection. Using for-loop, I want these column names as **"month, year, day"** using **my_fn**. Currently, I am getting the following error.

**ERROR LOG** - This is what I am getting as an error

```
SQL Error: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
*Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
           parse time or that is not of a nested table type
*Action:   use CAST to cast the item to a nested table type
```

**SQL CODE** - Here is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE col_array as table of varchar2(1000);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_fn (
    input_1 IN VARCHAR2,
    input_2 IN VARCHAR2,
    input_3 IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN varchar2 AS
      tmp col_array;
      txt varchar2(1000);

    BEGIN
    SELECT column_name bulk collect into tmp
    FROM all_tab_cols 
    where owner = 'me' and table_name ='my_table'; 

      for i in 1..tmp.count loop
        txt := txt || to_char( tmp(i) ) || ',';
      end loop;

    //txt := 'wow';

    RETURN txt;

    END my_fn;
/
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_fn('','',''));
```

I also tried the following simple code, but still not working. I may need more knowledge on how to use CAST function :(

```
BEGIN        
    txt := 'wow';    //or  txt := CAST('wow' as varchar2);         
RETURN txt;
```

Your help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function returns a string not a collection. You could use

```
SELECT my_fn('','','') FROM dual;
```

to get the value.